# Not able to update useState in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few state objects. Now I want to update all state objects to `true` when user will close `Modal`.

My code:

```js
const initialState = {
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false
  }

const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

const showModal = (e) => {
    
    setState({...initialState, [e.target.value] : true})
}

const hideModal = (e) => {
    
    setState({...initialState})
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: What do u mean state not updating, have you checked logging the state value? And how come showing model event have( e.target value) if so what is it referring to can u log it out and share here

Comment: can you share the code where the event listeners `showModal` and `hideModal` get used by the components. Should know what value the target will have.

Answer (score -1):

You can change each boolean by just accessing the current state while changing it.

```
function hideModal() {
  setState((current) => (current = { one: false, two: false, three: false }));
}

function showModal() {
  setState((current) => (current = { one: true, two: true, three: true }));
}
```